# How to set `null` as the default value for a nullable argument using SafeArgs?

Tags: android, androidx, android-architecture-navigation

How should I pass in `null` as default value for a String argument such as this:

```
<argument
    android:name="profile_id"
    android:defaultValue="???"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true" />
```

If the argument is nullable there should be a way to pass in `null` right?

Answer (score 122):

Turns out the good old `@null` works

```
<argument
    android:name="profile_id"
    android:defaultValue="@null"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true" />
```

Comment: Filed [this documentation issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120627532) to ensure that this is mentioned in the official documentation.

Comment: So you can't pass literal `@null` :|

Comment: according to @ianhanniballake comment - as of October 2022 - this way is allowed in official docs
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types