# can I send nullable data type as argument using safeargs ? if not what should I do?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

say I have 2 fragments. Login and Home. I set Home fragment as a global destination that has userData as arguments

[image]

if the user is not logged in yet, then it will start from login fragment. after login and get userData from server then it will navigate to Home and pass userData using this code

```
 val home = AuthenticationFragmentDirections.actionGlobalHomeFragment(userData)
 Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(home, navOptions)
```

but the problem is when the user already login and open the app. in this situation they will directly open the home fragment. and I my app crash with error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required argument "userData" is
>   missing and does not have an android:defaultValue

so I assume I can set nullable data type in arguments like `User?`  , so the Home fragment doesn't need userData if it doesn't come from Login

after reading from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661394/how-to-set-null-as-the-default-value-for-a-nullable-argument-using-safeargs), I set the argument like this to achieve `User?`

```
<argument
    android:name="userData"
    android:defaultValue="@null"
    app:argType="User"
    app:nullable="true" />
```

but the problem is, it said that I have too many arguments when I put user data to be sent to home from Login fragment

I use this in the gradle

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0-alpha04"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` to generate Safe Args in Kotlin?

Comment: Yes, as per the docs, that means you're generating Java code, - you have to use the `.kotlin` one to generate Kotlin code.

Comment: @ianhanniballake is it different from apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs' ? I use this in my gradle app

Comment: @ianhanniballake yup thats the problem. thank you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When using `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"`, only required arguments are passed to the `actionGlobalHomeFragment()` method - arguments with default values (i.e., ones that aren't required) are passed with the generated `set` methods:

```
val home = AuthenticationFragmentDirections.actionGlobalHomeFragment()
    .setUserData(userData)
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(home, navOptions)
```

If you were to switch to generating Kotlin Safe Args code by applying `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"` (note the `.kotlin`), then the code uses Kotlin default arguments (i.e., with `userData: UserData = null` in the method declaration), which **does** let you use the syntax you were initially trying:

```
val home = AuthenticationFragmentDirections.actionGlobalHomeFragment(userData)
Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(home, navOptions)
```

Comment: where can i add .setUserData(userData) method ?